# C++ How to use dlopen() in c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, dlopen

I am trying to use the prebuilt `tensorflow c-api` with a `cpp-wrapper` in my package. Unfortunately I am getting a segfault error. After searching I found out that there is a Git Issue about it: [Linking to both tensorflow and protobuf causes segmentation fault during static initializers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24976).

So I could resolve the Issues by doing:

> The workarounds sound like (1) only load the second copy of protobuf in a .so that does not use TensorFlow, and you can use both that .so and TensorFlow's .so from your main program, (2) instead of linking normally, dlopen() TensorFlow with RTLD_DEEPBIND set so TensorFlow prefers its own symbols.

I want to try to load the library using dlopen(), unfortunately I have never used it and I cannot find a good example of its use. How would I use it in my case and where?

My initial understanding:
Load it into the header of my cpp-wrapper since they use the tensorflow functions/header?
But than do I really need to change every single function of the cpp-wrapper header, and put a reference to the loaded handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little [`dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) example:

---

Some lib written in C, we call it `foobar.so`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() { printf("foo\n"); }
void bar() { printf("bar\n"); }
```

`gcc -o foobar.so foobar.c -shared -fPIC`

---

A (foobar) wrapper in C++

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct FooBar {

    typedef void (*foo_handle)(); //same signature as in the lib
    typedef void (*bar_handle)(); //same signature as in the lib

    foo_handle foo;
    bar_handle bar;
    void *foobar_lib;

    FooBar() {

        //probably best not in the constructor, but we're lazy (for now)
        //and of course no error checking (so don't)
        foobar_lib = dlopen("./foobar.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
        foo = reinterpret_cast<foo_handle>(dlsym(foobar_lib, "foo"));
        bar = reinterpret_cast<bar_handle>(dlsym(foobar_lib, "bar"));

    }

    ~FooBar() {
        dlclose(foobar_lib);
    }

};

int main()
{
    FooBar foobar;
    foobar.foo();
    foobar.bar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*foo_handle)(); //same signature as in the lib
typedef void (*bar_handle)(); //same signature as in the lib

foo_handle foo;
bar_handle bar;
void *foobar_lib;

int main()
{
    foobar_lib = dlopen("./foobar.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);

    foo = reinterpret_cast<foo_handle>(dlsym(foobar_lib, "foo"));
    bar = reinterpret_cast<bar_handle>(dlsym(foobar_lib, "bar"));

    foo();
    bar();

    dlclose(foobar_lib);
    
    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -ldl -o foobar_test foobar_test.cpp`

---

For each and every symbol you use from the original lib, you will have to call [`dlsym`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to obtain its address.

So yes, it is a tedious work, since you're implementing a wrapper to provide the full functionality of the underlying library.

For example, opengl developers knows very well what that means. Luckily, over the years there are now many tools available, which helps to load the myriads of symbols in runtime with no/less effort. Maybe there is something similar to tensorflow.

Comment: Wow thank you!!! So now I think I have two options. 1)Try to modify the cpp wrapper. By calling dlsym to every symbol? Or maybe just every symbol that I am using of the wrapper, since I should get a undefined reference for each that is used?


2) Try to to build the tensorflow c++api myself and than only dlsym all functions I really use. 

And one last question. Can you dlopen more than one .so file? Since the tensorflow c-api gives you more than one binary, and I dont know which one has which function..

Comment: Oh, i thought you build the cpp-wrapper. No matter, yes, the simpliest way would be to retrieve only the symbols you need. Your decision. And yes, you can load as many libraries as you want. Read the dlopen manpage on how dependencies are loaded as well (if that is an issue). dlopen simply loads the library file into memory, and dlsym looks for the location of the specified symbol.

Comment: ok interesting! No I am actually using this wrapper: https://github.com/serizba/cppflow, it consist of only header, so I think I could somehow find out which functions are really called and only link them and not all functions in the wrapper..